# jquery menu fade in out section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to navigate from menu using jquery.
My page display 1 section at the moment, and all page contains 3 sections. I would like to after clicking on menu section to fadeout current section and load cliccked section.

My code looks like:

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top top_menu  ">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class=" " >
                    <a href="#glowna">Main page
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class=" " >
                    <a href="#projekty" >Forums
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="" >
                    <a href="#kontakt">Contact
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


<section id="main page" ></section>
<section id="Forum" ></section>
<section id="Contact" ></section>
```

script

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('section').fadeOut(400);
  $('section #'+this).fadeIn(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `id` of your clicked anchor using `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')` or `$(this).prop('id')`:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('section').fadeOut(400);
    var id = this.id; //  or $(this).attr('id') or $(this).prop('id')
    $('section #'+id).fadeIn(400);
});
```

You can read more about [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 0):

finally . it works like this

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $('section').fadeOut(400);
   var id = $(this).attr('href');
   $(id).fadeIn(400);
});
```